# Context images / figures and linenumbering

Tags: graphics, floats, context, line-numbering

When typesetting a document with linenumbering, I get heavy problems with images. The linenumbering becomes a mess. What do I do wrong?
Here is an MWE:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\setupexternalfigures[location={local,default}]
\setupcaption[number=no]
\starttext

\startlinenumbering
\input tufte
\placefigure[outer]{}{\externalfigure[cow][width=30mm]}
\input tufte
\placefigure[left,none]{}{\framed[height=1cm]{graphic}}
\input tufte
\placefigure[none,right]{}{\externalfigure[cow][height=2cm]}
\input tufte
\stoplinenumbering

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean with: "I get a not asked for blank line before the paragraph"

Comment: Well, when I only use \placefigure, I don's get a new paragraph. \startplacefigure seems to start a new paragraph.

Comment: I updated the MWE with \startplacefigure

Comment: @Jan `\startplacefigure ... \stopplacefigure` is the same as `\placefigure{...}{...}` and you can’t just use them nested.

Comment: Oke, I'll delete then in the MWE, and let's return to the main question: what about the mess in the linenumbering?

Comment: @Jan Can you show what you mean with the messy output because I can’t see anything wrong when I use the current beta.

Comment: I've updated my question. I work with TeXLive and TeXworks. When I compile my MWE, I get some errors too. (I've tried to get working the standalone-ConTeXt  version with Scite, but without succes...

Comment: I take it you are using placeins and lineno?

Comment: @JohnKormylo `placeins` and `lineno` are LaTeX only, aren't they?

Comment: @Jan Can we close this questions? It seems to be a bug in the version shipped with TL which is already fixed in the beta. So you either have to wait until TL deploys the fix or use the standalone version (recommended).

Comment: @DG' I think you would be justified in copying your comment to the *Answer* box. You've provided a solution to the problem that Jan wants to solve.

Comment: @TEV ok then, I turned the comment into an aswer

Comment: Thank you both, I already began to fear something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [TEV](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31316/tev) asked me to:  It seems to be a bug in the version shipped with TL which is already fixed in the beta. So you either have to wait until TL deploys the fix or use the standalone version (recommended).